# Why doesn't Switch in Flutter change value when I tap it but only on drag?

Tags: user-interface, flutter

When I try Switch from examples/flutter_gallery I can tap it to change value.

```
bool switchOn = false;

void _onSwitchChanged(bool value) {
  switchOn = false;
}

body: 
ListView(
 children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
         Switch(
           onChanged: _onSwitchChanged,
           value: switchOn,
         ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Add coding example, please!

Comment: and you cannot see how they did it in `examples/flutter_gallery` sources?

Comment: They are using setState(), I don't see how that affects on switch behavior

Comment: ok, what "switches" do you mean? what is the label around them?

Comment: ListView( Row ( Switch  ()

Comment: i mean switches in `flutter_gallery`

Comment: Allign( Row( Switch.adaptive

Comment: change `setState(() {switchOn = value;});`

Comment: yes, it appears that is solution, do you have idea why it adds onTap effect ?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you need to use `setState()` method whenever you want the screen to refresh. So in reality the value of `switchOn` is actually changing however this change is not being rendered on the screen because you're not using `setState()` You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-state-management-setstate-fn-is-the-easiest-and-the-most-powerful-44703c97f035)

```
 bool switchOn = false;

   void _onSwitchChanged(bool value) {
      setState(() {
        switchOn = false;
      });
    }

body: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Switch(
                      onChanged: _onSwitchChanged,
                      value: switchOn,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: This would be in the comment section. This is not the answer.

Comment: Yes I just don't have enough rep to do that yet, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

you should update state to change value

```
void _onSwitchChanged(bool value) {
   setState((){
      switchOn = false;
   });      
}
```

Comment: Why Switch changes with Drag without it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue whene build for web it become hard to darge the switch and you need some way to update it on tap so you can user `AbsorbPointer` on the switch and you handle the update by `GestureDetector` or build a custom switch like this (make the code batter ):

```
class MSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onChange;
  final bool value, round;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color unActiveColor;
  final double width, height;
  MSwitch(
      {this.value,
      this.onChange,
      this.activeColor = Colors.green,
      this.unActiveColor = Colors.grey,
      this.width = 40,
      this.height = 20,
      this.round = true});
  @override
  _MSwitchState createState() => _MSwitchState();
}

class _MSwitchState extends State<MSwitch> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  bool value;
  @override
  void initState() {
    value = widget.value ?? false;
    super.initState();
    if (value)
     Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
        controller.animateTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
     });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double fullWidth = (widget.width - (widget.height / 2)) * 2;
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            value = !value;
          });
          if (widget.onChange != null) widget.onChange(value);

          if (controller.position.pixels == 0) {
            controller.animateTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
          } else {
            controller.animateTo(0,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
          }
        },
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.height),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height,
            child: ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior: CustomBehavior(),
              child: ListView(
                controller: controller,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: fullWidth,
                    height: widget.height,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: fullWidth / 2),
                          width: fullWidth / 2,
                          height: widget.height,
                          color: widget.activeColor,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: fullWidth / 2),
                          width: fullWidth / 2,
                          height: widget.height,
                          color: widget.unActiveColor,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: (fullWidth / 2) - (widget.height / 2)),
                          width: widget.height,
                          height: widget.height,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                  widget.round ? widget.height : 0),
                              color: Colors.white),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
class CustomBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```